# Log messages via TCP, significantly slower than similar code in Java

Tags: python, performance, sockets, logging, tcp

In Python 3 I have a QueueHandler attached to a Logger and a QueueListener shipping the LogRecords to a SocketHandler which sends the logs via TCP to a Java app that's listening.

Both programs run on localhost.

```
import logging
import queue

log_q = queue.Queue(-1)
logger = logging.getLogger('TestLogger')
socket_handler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost', 1337)
q_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_q)
q_listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(log_q, socket_handler)
logger.addHandler(q_handler)
q_listener.start()
```

I'm sending LogRecords with fairly large lists attached to them.

```
logger.info("PROX_MARKER", extra={'vector': [some_list]})
```

where `[some_list]` is a list of ~100k double values.

I run the following code to test the throughput:

```
for i in range(1000):
    logger.info("PROX_MARKER", extra={'vector': [some_list]})
```

Which takes about 30-35 seconds to complete.

If I run a similar test in Java, the Java app is about twice as fast.

In Python the QueueHandler/-Listener + SocketHandler setup manages to send about 3 messages for every 10 put in the queue. By the time the program finishes it'll have sent ~300 msgs with about 700 still in the queue which will than slowly get sent after the main program already finished.

The QueueHandler/-Listener I use are default, the only change to the default SocketHandler is that I use a custom serializing method.

My goal (in case this wasn't obvious) is to try and speed up the python code. Unfortunately I'm still not 100% sure what's causing this slow behavior in the first place. It might have something to do with the socket (which I know very little about, I've tried playing around with various timeout setting and TCP_NODELAY - to no avail).

I've tried to ditch the QueueHandler/-Listener and just use the SocketHandler directly which takes about the same amount of time as before so I'm assuming that threading isn't an issue.

Any tips on what the issue might be or how to make this faster are very much appreciated.

Comment: Run a profiler on the code to see where the time is going. Use just the socket handler with custom serialisation and then again with the default serialisation. What differences do you see?

Comment: Profiler really isn't all that helpful. It just tells me that the program spends 80% of it's runtime locking threads which makes sense seeing how after the main program finishes the Queue thread is still running to clear the queue. There's no other noteworthy method in the profiler output apart from lock.acquire(). I tried the default serialisation. It is indeed faster (17s vs 27s). I use the same custom serializer in Java (ProtoBuf) and it runs fine. I use pyrobuf in Python which has worked for me in the past. But hey, thanks for helping, at least now I know that  it's ProtoBuf / PyroBuf.